# Problem mounting SD Card

Tags: 18.04, mount, sd-card

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to use my 128GB SD Card. I have no idea what I am doing and I have done research on how to do this but nothing is working. Some websites say I need to become root user but problems happen when I try.

Does anyone know how to mount an SD Card on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with the steps and methods you tried, as well as their results and error messages so we can understand better your situation. Also: are you trying to mount and transfer data using the terminal or the gui?

Comment: So, I am trying to mount my SD Card so I can copy and transfer files. I have tried many different options that I have now forgotten but the main one was installing the exFAT driver which helps to read USBs with the exFAT format. I have plugged in my other SD Card which is 8GB and restarted my laptop. Occasionally the SD Card shows up but when I remove and re-insert the SD Card it is not read by the laptop. Do you have any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you able to read and write data on the SD in other machines? Can you tell if it is not corrupt? exFAT is a windows filesystem and therefore not supported by default in many linux OS, unless you install additional packages. What exFAT debian did you install? Try to add as many details as you can remember to help us understand your error.

Comment: Um, I use a Mac normally and the SD Card works on the mac.

I used:
Sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils

Comment: I am using a micro SD Card. I forgot to say that.